# How to rotate a set of pictures from the command line?

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, gimp

I have a large set of JPEG pictures all with the same resolution. It would take too long to open each one inside the graphical interface of imagemagic or gimp.

How do I achieve each picture being rotated and saved as the same filename?

Comment: See [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/photos/#orient).  Beware however that re-encoding JPEG is generally lossy.

Comment: See also: [SuperUser: How to rotate images automatically, based on exif data](https://superuser.com/questions/36645/how-to-rotate-images-automatically-based-on-exif-data).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can use the `convert` command:

```
convert input.jpg -rotate <angle in degrees> out.jpg
```

To rotate 90 degrees clockwise:

```
convert input.jpg -rotate 90 out.jpg
```

To save the file with the same name:

```
convert file.jpg -rotate 90 file.jpg
```

To rotate all files:

```
for photo in *.jpg ; do convert $photo -rotate 90 $photo ; done
```

---

Alternatively, you can also use the [`mogrify`](https://imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) command line tools (the best tool) recommended by [@don-crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22142/don-crissti):

```
mogrify -rotate 90 *.jpg
```

Comment: thx, how do I tell the command that the filename left of -rotate -180 has to be the same as right of it , if there are many files?

Comment: Rotating a file 180 degrees will always give you the same result, no matter if you rotate it left or right.

Comment: @GAD3R 360 degrees will result in the same image afterwards. Rotating an image left or right by 180 degrees, with both give you the same image (but upside down).

Comment: `$CAPITAL_NAMES` should be left to environment variables;  for those local variables in shell scripts or commands use `$normal_lowercase`

Comment: `convert` re-encodes JPEG and hence is lossy. Better use `jpegtran`

Comment: `mogrify`accepts just one filename to convert which `convert`does not.

Comment: `-rotate 90` (90° clockwise); `-rotate -90 (90° counter-clockwise)`

Answer (score 22):

For JPEG images and right-angle rotations, use [`jpegtran`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/jpegtran) or [`exiftran`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/exiftran), as they can rotate the images losslessly.

```
for f in *.jpg ; do 
    jpegtran -rotate 180 "$f" > "${f%.jpg}-rotated.jpg"
done
```

Or to rotate in-place:

```
for f in *.jpg ; do
    jpegtran -rotate 180 -outfile "$f" "$f"
done
```

`exiftran` also has the `-a` flag to automatically rotate the image based on what the EXIF orientation tag says.

Comment: For counter-clockwise (left-angle) rotation with `jpegtran`, use `-rotate 270` and with exiftran use `-2`flag according to the manual.

Comment: `*.jpg` works under bash but under zshell it causes the error `jpegtran: can't open *.jpg for reading` but `*jpg` works for me in zshell.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the two other answers may provide different results depending on the EXIF Orientation : it seems that `convert` rotates with regards to the EXIF Orientation, while `jpegtran` just ignores the EXIF Orientation.

This observation led me to figure I actually needed to discard the EXIF Orientation, so I just used `exiftool` to discard EXIF data without further data loss (that's also what does `jpegtran` when no `-rotate` option is given, it seems) :

```
exiftool -all= -o outfile.jpg infile.jpg
```

I could have just removed the EXIF Orientation with

```
exiftool -Orientation= -o outfile.jpg infile.jpg
```

or modified it with

```
exiftool -n -Orientation=1 -o outfile.jpg infile.jpg
```

(for this later case you will need to read [the FAQ](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q6) to understand option `-n`, needed for `exiftool` to translate the `-Orientation` value, and [the EXIF tags table](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/EXIF.html)).

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, however I found it whilst searching for a solution for this very task.

The problem with `jpegtran` is that it does rotate the image, but it discards all the EXIF header data.

`exiftool` keeps it, but it's not very handy to use.

Thus, I wrote a small script to rotate a JPEG image by 90°, keeping the EXIF header. Maybe someone may find this useful:

```
#!/bin/bash

orientation=$(exiftool -n -Orientation "$1")

if [[ "$?" != "0" ]]; then
    exit 1
fi

orientation=${orientation##*: }

if [[ "$orientation" == "1" ]]; then
    # 1 = Horizontal (normal)
    target="6"
elif [[ "$orientation" == "6" ]]; then
    # 6 = Rotate 90 CW
    target="3"
elif [[ "$orientation" == "3" ]]; then
    # 3 = Rotate 180
    target="8"
elif [[ "$orientation" == "8" ]]; then
    # 8 = Rotate 270 CW
    target="1"
else
    echo "Can't process orientation \"$orientation\""
    exit 1
fi

extension=${1/*./}
backup="${1%$extension*}orig.$extension"

mv "$1" "$backup" || exit 1

exiftool -n -Orientation=$target "$backup" -o "$1"
```

Comment: `jpegtran` has `-copy all` to copy exif and other metadata. Note that it doesn't rotate the thumbnail if  any.

Comment: Beware jpegtran will corrupt images that don't have width and height being precisely a multiple of 8 pixels (a sliver of the picture from one edge gets moved to the opposite edge). This behaviour is alluded to in the man page ("The  transpose  transformation  has no restrictions regarding image dimensions.  The other transformations operate rather oddly if the image dimensions are not a multiple of the iMCU size (usually 8 or 16  pixels),  because  they  can only transform complete blocks of DCT coefficient data in the desired way").